# jQueryMobile and backbone - how to load "routers/mobileRouter"

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs, yeoman

I'm trying to setup a project using jQueryMobile, Backbone and RequireJs. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
require([ "jquery", "backbone", "routers/mobileRouter" ], 
    function( $, Backbone, Mobile ) {
        /* do something */
    }
) ;
```

It is actually coming from [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/pages/backbone-require.html). Running the code gives a 404 on 'routers/mobileRouter'

```
GET http://localhost:9000/scripts/routers/mobileRouter.js 404 (Not Found)
```

For example, if I search for 'mobileRouter.js' in my project I get the following

```
./app/bower_components/jquery-mobile/demos/examples/backbone-require/js/routers/mobileRouter.js
./app/bower_components/jquery-mobile/dist/demos/examples/backbone-require/js/routers/mobileRouter.js
```

These are demos/examples, so how should I load this, maybe I need to install an other package ? Any link to some documentation about this would of course help me too!

UPDATE: here is all the js code

```
// Sets the require.js configuration for your application.
require.config( {

    // 3rd party script alias names (Easier to type "jquery" than "libs/jquery-1.8.3.min")
    paths: {
        // Core Libraries
        jquery:      '../bower_components/jquery/jquery',
        backbone:    '../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
        underscore:  '../bower_components/underscore/underscore',
        jquerymobile:'../bower_components/jquery-mobile/dist/jquery.mobile.min'

    },

    // Sets the configuration for your third party scripts that are not AMD compatible
    shim: {

        "backbone": {
            "deps": [ "underscore", "jquery" ],
            "exports": "Backbone"  //attaches "Backbone" to the window object
        },
        "jquery.mobile": ['jquery']
    } // end Shim Configuration
} );

// Includes File Dependencies
require([ "jquery", "backbone", "routers/mobileRouter" ], function( $, Backbone, Mobile )       {

    $( document ).on( "mobileinit",
        // Set up the "mobileinit" handler before requiring jQuery Mobile's module
        function() {
            // Prevents all anchor click handling including the addition of active button state and alternate link bluring.
            $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;

            // Disabling this will prevent jQuery Mobile from handling hash changes
            $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
        }
    );

    require( [ "jquerymobile" ], function() {
        // Instantiates a new Backbone.js Mobile Router
        this.router = new Mobile();
    });
} );
```

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. Its just stuff they wrote for [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/demos/examples/backbone-require) demo :) Its their implementation of backbone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another key/value to your paths:

```
paths: {
    // Core Libraries
    jquery:      '../bower_components/jquery/jquery',
    backbone:    '../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
    underscore:  '../bower_components/underscore/underscore',
    jquerymobile:'../bower_components/jquery-mobile/dist/jquery.mobile.min',
    jquerymobilerouter: '../bower_components/jquery-mobile/demos/examples/backbone-require/js/routers/mobileRouter.js'
},
```

then you can use it like this:

```
require(["jquery", "backbone", "jquerymobilerouter"], function($, Backbone, MobileRouter) {
});
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't sound right. It solves the router issue, but now I've got a couple of new 404. Now RequireJs tries to load things like http://localhost:9000/models/CategoryModel.js, http://localhost:9000/collections/CategoriesCollection.js, http://localhost:9000/views/CategoryView.js. Something is just wrong :(

Comment: Well, the change I proposed has nothing to do with that model, collection and view that are failing now. Do you have your path to those correctly set? I don't see ```baseUrl``` set anywhere in your require.config so that may be the cause.

Comment: your post was indeed the answer to the question. See my comment on my post above! Thnx!